# Drawing list view items by WM_DRAWITEM

Tags: c++, listview, winapi

I need to set height of list view items in win32 api so i use `LVS_OWNERDRAWFIXED` to get `WM_MEASUREITEM` 
message and set height of items.But when i use `LVS_OWNERDRAWFIXED` in `CreateWindow()` when creating the list, 
all items that i inserted by `ListView_InsertItem()` unappeared.

I have read in this case should draw items when `WM_DRAWITEM` is sent to the parent window procedure.I know there is a pointer to `DRAWITEMSTRUCT` struct in the `lParam` but i dont know how to force it to display the items.

I have the following code inside `WinMain()` :

```
 HWND hwndList1 = CreateWindow(WC_LISTVIEW , L"" ,  WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | LVS_REPORT | WS_BORDER  |  WS_VSCROLL | LVS_OWNERDRAWFIXED , 10 , 10 , width , height, hwnd, NULL, GetModuleHandle(NULL), 0); 
 CreateItem(hwndList1 , "My item");
```

And these are `CreateItem()` and `WndProc()` :

```
int CreateItem(HWND hwndList, char*  Text)
{ 
  LVITEM lvi = {0};

  lvi.mask = LVIF_TEXT | LVCF_FMT | LVCFMT_LEFT;
  lvi.pszText = (LPWSTR)Text;

return ListView_InsertItem(hwndList, &lvi);
} 


LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc( HWND hwnd , UINT msg , WPARAM wParam , LPARAM lParam)
{
switch(msg){


  case WM_DRAWITEM:{ //I dont know what to do
     }
     break;

  case WM_MEASUREITEM:{
            MEASUREITEMSTRUCT* m= (MEASUREITEMSTRUCT*) lParam;
            m->itemHeight=25;
            }
            break;

  case WM_CLOSE:
    DestroyWindow( hwnd );
    break;

  case WM_DESTROY:
    PostQuitMessage(0);
    break;

  default:
    return DefWindowProc( hwnd , msg , wParam , lParam );
 }
return 0;
}
```

Please how to draw and display items?

Comment: First, you need to be consistent in using `char` or `wchar_t` - don't mix them up and just cast one to the other!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To handle WM_DRAWITEM, you need to actually draw each item using WinAPI GDI calls!
As a starting point, the following may give you some clues:

```
case WM_DRAWITEM: { //I dont know what to do
    LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT pDIS = (LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT)(lParam);
    HDC hDC = pDIS->hDC;
    RECT rc = pDIS->rcItem;
    HBRUSH bg = (HBRUSH)(::GetStockObject(LTGRAY_BRUSH));
    HPEN pn = (HPEN)(::GetStockObject(BLACK_PEN));
    ::SelectObject(hDC, bg);
    ::SelectObject(hDC, pn);
    ::SetTextColor(hDC, RGB(0, 0, 0));
    const wchar_t *text = L"Dummy Text";
    ::Rectangle(hDC, rc.left, rc.top, rc.right, rc.bottom);
    ::DrawText(hDC, text, wcslen(text), &rc, DT_SINGLELINE | DT_VCENTER);
}
break;
```

Obviously, there's a lot more you will need to do in a real-world program, like fetching the actual text for the item and changing the colours of text and background, depending on the selection state, etc. You can get much of the information you need from the various members of the `DRAWITEMSTRUCT` that is passed.

If this is helpful, let me know and we can think about further refinements. But try this 'dummy run' first, and see if it works and you can understand what's happening.

Comment: Thank you so much works perfectly..Please can you tell me how can i remove borders around items?

Comment: Easy! In the call to `::Rectangle(…)` you are using the selected background brush and pen. I gave you a stock object of `BLACK_PEN` but you can use `NULL_PEN` to get no border (well, an invisible one).

Comment: Dear Adrian, I need to get the actual text of list item and draw it.I try this `LPTSTR text=(LPTSTR)"";
ListView_GetItemText( pDIS -> hwndItem , pDIS -> itemID , 0 ,text, 1000);
rc.left=12;
::DrawText( hDC , text  , wcslen(text) , &rc , DT_SINGLELINE | DT_VCENTER );` but i get a runtime exception.Please what am i doing wrong?Is there a better way for it?Thanks

Comment: @Zahra19977 - Where you have `LPTSTR text = (LPTSTR)"";` you are creating a text buffer of length 1 character! But, in your `_GetItemText()` call you tell the system you have a buffer of 1000 characters! Try using `TCHAR text[1000];` instead. But it's good that you found out how to use `pDIS->itemID` by yourself.